# Нестандартное условие в MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с полями: `gorod`, `category`

нужно в запросе сделать условие, чтобы допустим выводились записи из города `moskva` и из категорий `avto` и `tehnika`.

Сейчас делаю так:

```
SELECT * FROM baza WHERE gorod = 'moskva' AND cat = 'avto'
```

Как тут добавить еще условие, чтобы и из категории `tehnika` выводились записи? Если ставлю еще `AND cat = 'tehnika'`, то конечно же ничего не выводит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM baza WHERE gorod = 'moskva' AND cat IN ('avto', 'tehnika')
```

или

```
SELECT * FROM baza WHERE gorod = 'moskva' AND (cat = 'avto' OR cat = 'tehnika')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает!

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM baza WHERE gorod = 'moskva' AND (cat = 'avto' OR cat = 'tehnika');`